# get the last weeks date from given date

Tags: python

I am trying to find the date of the of the last week. For instance lets say my date is '2021-01-02' in that specific date time format. How do i go about getting the date of the past week.
I originally tried but I get this error. I believe its because i have the date as a string but i need to have the dates in the yyyy-mm-dd format

```
x = '2021-01-02'
pervious_data =  datetime.date.x.shift(-7)
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-09dc0b383193> in <module>
      1 x='2021-03-05'
----> 2 pervious_data =  datetime.date.x.shift(-7)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Comment: What is `.x` supposed to be?

Comment: `x` is a string. How do you expect to subtract 7 days from a string? You need to convert it to datetime.

Comment: i guess what im asking is how do i convert the x value('2021-01-02') to a date time then use the .shift(-7) or any other method to get the date of the pervious week.

Answer (score 1):

The method `datetime.datetime.strptime` is able to convert the string into a special datetime object, which in turn can be turned into a date object.

After that, you need only create a `datetime.timedelta` instance of a single week and subtract it from your date.

```py
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.strptime("2021-01-02", "%Y-%m-%d").date()
previous_data = x - datetime.timedelta(weeks=1)
```